# How can I copy dynamically generated source HTML from the web?

Tags: javascript, html

For design purposes, I want to copy the exact HTML that is created by some JavaScript after the page loads. Firebug shows me what's going on, of course, but I really just want some static text that I can copy and paste at will.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "View Source" menu of the [Web Developer](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) Firefox Add-on offers the "View Generated Source" tool.

Comment: "View Generated Source" is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks lance!

Comment: If Web Developer could wear a cape, I'm convinced it would rescue people from falling buildings.

Answer (score 6):

That can be done with the `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` properties. Or just in Firefox, select the part you want the source code from and select *View Selection Source* from the context menu.

Answer (score 4):

You can copy the HTML out of firebug (or the IE8 developer toolset) into your favourite text editor.

Answer (score 3):

In Google Chrome, choose Inspect Element, then you can right click and "Copy as HTML"

Comment: Note that with this method you get the script as well as what it does to the DOM (with some space added, in my experience): `<html><body><script type="text/javascript">document.write("foo");</script></body></html>`

Answer (score 0):

For IE/firefox, following bookmarklet works:
https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html#generated_source

For google chrome, right click on any element and choose 'Inspect Element' option. It will show the position of element in DOM. Now right click on '

For opera, right click on any element and choose 'Inspect element'. This will start opera dragonfly. In dragonfly window, Click on 'Expand the DOM tree' button (first button with a dot and two arrows) and then 'export the current DOM panel' button (second button)

In IE, open the webpage and press F12 to open developer tools. Click View->Source->DOM(page) or shortcut Ctrl+Shift+G in developer tools window. This will show the complete currently visible DOM.

For firefox, alternative is [Web developer toolbar extension](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) and choose View Source->View Generated source in it.

Answer (score -1):

you could also write a perl script with the Library mechanize.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize doesn't support JavaScript. There are alternatives listed at https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize::FAQ#JavaScript